# array to xml fails in the middle of process

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

As you can see below, everything go well up to `uid` and `pwd` elements. Suddenly swoops places with values. AM I missing something here?

Original code is [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml).

**CODE:**

```
$array = array('table'=>'users', 'operation'=>'insert', 'uid'=>'yoyo', 'pwd'=>'123');
$output = serialize($array);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive(unserialize($output), array($xml, 'addChild'));
echo $xml->asXML();
```

**RESULT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<users>table</users>
<insert>operation</insert>
<yoyo>uid</yoyo>
<123>pwd</123>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your need you have to flip your array so try,

Changing your line

```
$output = serialize($array);
```

with

```
$output = serialize(array_flip($array));
```